# Is it possible to mix columns with a horizontal line on each category?

Tags: highcharts

I have an idea how I can improve the user experience by altering some of my charts. Basically I have a column chart, where I display some values per category. The last value I display is the average.

I want to display the average value as a dotted line in each category.

[Paint picture of idea displayed as a single category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1brOj.png)

I have read the documentation more times than I'm happy to admit, but I have still not found a proper solution. My best attempt was to overload the circle symbol in the 'scatter'-series and then redraw it as an SVG.

Does anyone have an idea to how I should approach it? I feel the option must be there, and I'm just missing the forest for the trees.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `line` series type with calculated data:

```
const averageData = [3.33, 3.33, 3.66];
const processedAverageData = [];

averageData.forEach((val, index) => {
    processedAverageData.push([index - 0.4, val], [index + 0.4, val]);
    // To create gaps between categories
    processedAverageData.push(null);
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    series: [{
        ...
    }, {
        ...
    }, {
        ...
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        data: processedAverageData,
        dashStyle: 'dash',
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t3ejqvun/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line

Comment: Thank you soo much. I will try out the approach asap and mark the response accordingly :D